# Pros and cons of hosting a SPA in GCS

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-storage, hosting, google-kubernetes-engine, single-page-application

We normally host an SPA built with React JS in GKE.

But we thought it will be an overkill to host an SPA in GKE, so we are thinking to host SPA in [GCS Bucket](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-webapp-hosting-gcs#0)

Can someone help us understand the pros and cons of both the below approaches

1. Hosting a SPA in GKE
2. Hosting a SPA in GCS Bucket

Comment: Did you have consider App Engine? And your question will be closed because it's opinionated....

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere We have ruled out app engine for its pricing and other reasons